# Respond to an AJAX request in express

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

How to send a response to a ajax request and then redirecting the user without showing him the response?

I have been able to send the data to the server with but I wasn't able to send the response back to the JavaScript file and then redirecting the user.

If I remove the `redirect(302, '/')`, I can see the json result on the browser but I want to send the data to the ajax request and then redirect.

Routes

```
var express = require('express');
var url = require('.././models/first.js');
var router = express.Router();


router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    res.render('index');
    res.end();
})

router.post('/add',function(req,res) {

    var patt = /(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;

    var url = req.body.url //This variable gets the value

    if(patt.test(url) === false) {
        res.send({mes: 'Invalid'},
        res.redirect(302,'/')); // this data doesn't reach the file.
    } else {
        res.send({mes: 'Okay'},
        res.redirect(302,'/'));
    }


})

module.exports = router;
```

External/static javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#urlform').submit(function(e) {
        var patt = /(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/g;
        var url = $("#area").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "jsonp",
            data: {url: url},
            url: 'localhost:7000/add',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#url').text(data.url);
            }
        })
    })
})
```

index.jade

```
extends ../public/layouts/default

block content
    #onlydiv
        #onlydiv-inside
            p Paste your URL below to shorten it
            form#urlform(action='/add', method='post')
                input#area(type='text' name='url', placeholder = 'www.facebook.com', autocomplete = 'off' required)
                input#button(type='submit')
            p#url
```

Comment: You can't redirect in an ajax request like that, the ajax request is a request of it's own, redirecting won't change the parent page. Also, you don't prevent the default submit action, so the page probably reloads.

Comment: I removed the form and when clicked on button send ajax request. It still doesn't work. Do you any workaround? How to send the data back without the user seeing the data

Comment: Just remove the redirect, and output something, it will be returned to the success function

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked exactly like I wanted it to.